# jquery Change Child Deminsions to match Parents after resize

Tags: jquery, parent, resizable

I have a parent div with a child div inside. The parent div is using jquery Ui resizable. How can i make the child div inherent the parent div dimensions in real time when parent div is resized.

Here's what i have
http://jsfiddle.net/dtxhe/7/

After resize, the child div is not resizing according to it's parent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also use this :

http://jsfiddle.net/dtxhe/11/

Code :

```
$("#container").resizable({ alsoResize: '#child' });
```

Comment: +1, this is nice and clean.  The rest of us are duplicating the functionality already provided by jQuery UI.

Answer (score 2):

You need to utilize the `resize` event of the resizable object.

http://jsfiddle.net/dtxhe/10/

```
$("#container").resizable({
   resize: function(event, ui) {
       var parentwidth = $("#container").innerWidth();
       var parentheight = $("#container").innerHeight();
       $("#child").css({'width':parentwidth, 'height':parentheight});
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the size of the child to fit parent in the $.resize event.
e.g(changed the code to reduce jquery selector calls):

```
$("#container").resize(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var parentwidth = $this.innerWidth();
    var parentheight = $this.innerHeight();
   $("#child").css({'width':parentwidth, 'height':parentheight});
});
$("#container").resizable();
$("#container").resize();
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Chandu/dtxhe/9/

Answer (score 0):

You must bind to the resize event, like so:  http://jsfiddle.net/bWMxm/2/